# How to convert list to queue in scala

Tags: scala, list, queue

I tried this:

```
var myQueue = scala.collection.mutable.Queue(myList)
```

Where list contains elements, let's say: List(1,2,3,4,5)

I want a queue with the same elements with the list such as: Queue(1,2,3,4,5).
But what I got is: Queue(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

Any idea?

Comment: btw: you should avoid using `var` and mutable collections when programming Scala. There is (almost) always a way to do it in another way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the list as a vararg:

```
val myList = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

val myQueue = scala.collection.mutable.Queue(myList: _*)
// Queue(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```